# Disable additional logs in log4j

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j

how can we disable additional logs from the console in log4j at runtime and show only those needed for the Spring boot application?

Comment: what are "additional logs"?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-disable-console-logging this link may be helpful for you.

Comment: @f1sh "additional logs" means the log in the console which we see while starting application. While i need to show only those logs at runtime related to that applications.